# want to redirect to next page on particular section id without showing #id in the url

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone help me please using javascript on the following problem.
I want to redirect to next page on particular section id without showing "#id" in the url using javascript or jquery.

Comment: <a href="whatever#id">click here</a> will show only "click here" to the end user!

Answer (score 0):

Well I suppose you could store the id using HTML5 local storage then when you load the next page you can remove it and scroll the user there.

I don't recommend that you do this. It's good that the URL has the id so the user can send the URL linking directly to that section to other people.